# Easy way to compare values of 4 parametres c#?

Tags: c#, compare

Hi I have 4 strings.

```
string a,b,c, d;
```

I want to compare all of them. How I can I do it easily.

```
bool ret=true;

if(a==b) {ret=false;}
if(a==c) {ret=false;}
if(a==d) {ret=false;}
if(b==c) {ret=false;}
if(b==d) {ret=false;}
if(c==d) {ret=false;}
....
...
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Add a,b,c and d to a dictionary, then count the entries ... 4 means no duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for something that checks if any two elements are equal, you can create a set and check if the number of elements in the set is equal to the number of elements that were input.

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] {a, b, c, d};
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(stringArray);

ret = set.Count == stringArray.Length;
```

Comment: Yes i'm looking if any are equal. thank you so much. it's working.

Comment: @user3583183 Great. Since this is what you're looking for, note my edit. If you're trying to determine if two of any given strings are equal, you can also use a HashSet. See [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438).

Comment: Hashset is very easy. I didn't try before but i like it this way. Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works?

```
if (a==b==c==d)
```

or

```
if (a==b && b==c && c==d)
```

Comment: I guess the OP ment **at least one pair** being equal

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = new[] { a, b, c, d }; 
if (strings.Distinct ().Count() > 1) 
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: if he mean at least one pair didn't your condition should be

    strings.Distinct().Count() < strings.length

Comment: The check he's doing is looking to see if any of the values match. If so, then he returns false.  This string.Distinct().Count() approach identifies if there are 2 or more strings with different values.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can put it in array and

```
string[] a = new string[4] { "a", "b", "d", "d" };
string result = a.Where(x => a.Count(z => z == x) > 1).FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
    ret = false;
}
```